# Tornado: How to write in template when image is used for background-image?

Tags: css, templates, background-image, render, tornado

For exmaple, I render the image's url to "exmaple.html".

```
self.render("example.html", image=image)
```

Then in template: How to write if I want it to be used for background image?

I try this in CSS file：

```
background-image: url({{image}});
```

But it does not work.

Many thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you serving your css as a static file or a template?  You must make it a template to have expressions like `{{image}}` interpreted.  (but be careful - Tornado doesn't know anything about escaping text for inclusion in CSS, so if the image might include any user-supplied text you'll have to validate or escape it yourself).

Instead of making your CSS file a template, though, it's probably better to keep it static and put the varying parts in the HTML.  If the image is one of a few possibilities, you can just define a class for each one and reference the class in the html.  If there are too many possibilities to list, an inline style attribute might be the best way to do it (but see the previous comment about escaping)

Answer (score 0):

add a CSS block in your base template. And then you can use that to specify the CSS rules.

base_template.html :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Some Title</title>
    {% block css %}{% end %}
</head>
<body>
        {% block body %}{% end %}
</body>
</html>
```

In the file which will be rendered:

```
{% extends "base_template.html" %}
{% block css %}
<style type="text/css">
    background-image: url( {{ image }} );
</style>
{% end %}
```